# No funciona el If tampoco Switch en un array de la base de datos Mysql con Php

Tags: php, mysql, array, variables, condiciones

Tenga esa consulta:

```
$base = "SELECT * FROM novedad N
JOIN empleados E ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE id='$id'";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
$crow = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);
```

eso me trae todos los datos de los empleados, hay un campo que me dice si el empleado cargo una novedad o no, el campo registra un si o un no.
[image: campos de la base]

el problema que tengo es que hago cuando hago el if si el empleado cargo novedad que muestre el html si no que no muestre nada.
pero no me funciona.
ese es mi codigo:

```
if ($crow['licencia1']=="No"){
echo "licencia: ".$crow['licencia1']; // imprimi licencia: No
}if ($crow['licencia1']=="Si"){
echo "licencia: ".$crow['licencia1'];// imprimi licencia: Si
}
```

no me trae nada, lo raro es que si hago un:

```
echo "licencia: ".$crow['licencia1'];
```

me devuelve el resultado, pero si coloco adentro del if, no me trae nada, ya intente con switch tambien y pasa lo mismo.
Desde ayer que estoy con eso y no veo donde esta el problema.

resultado de `var_dump($crow);`

[image: Resultado de var_dump($crow)]

Edite el campo de la tabla le puse text(2) y sigue el mismo problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo tu problema. El If que tienes muestra la misma salida que el echo. En un caso escribe "licencia: Si" y en otro "Licencia: No", que en este caso es lo mismo que concatenar el valor de $crow['licencia1']; Si quieres comprobarlo, añade un "echo A" y un "echo B" en cada una de las opciones, para que la salida pueda ser distinta.

Comment: Ahi edite haber si se entiede

Comment: quizas a lo que se refiere es que en caso "Si" que lo imprima, en caso "No" que no muestre nada.

Comment: Necesito validar porque no quiero muestra los que dicen NO, solo los que dice SI

Comment: Es que no es solo licencia1, hay varios campos diferentes necesito usar el if, o el switch en mas de 10 campos, por ejemplo, si llego tarde si o no, si esta enfermo, si o no, el problema es que el if no esta funcionando, yo uso el if en otros lugares y funciona.

Comment: Puede que sea el contenido de tu campo, puedes hacer un `var_dump($crow);` y mostrarnos el resultado.

Comment: edite la pregunta con el resultado de var_dump($crow);

Comment: Allí está el error, los datos del campo licencia1 tienen caracteres adicionales a Si y No, puedes ver que dice string(5) porque lo cual tiene 3 caracteres vacíos.

Comment: Y este amigo es uno de los problemas de almacenar un boleano como varchar o text en lugar de utilizar un enum o tinyint. Puedes ayudarte de `trim()` para eliminar los espacios del principio y el final. Y si utilizas mysql como parece le echaria un vistazo a `enum` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo si el campo 'licencia1' es igual a "Si" entonces deberia mostrar un codigo HTML, de lo contrario no deberia mostrar nada, entonces solo deberias colocar el "No" dentro de la condicion y en el else poner lo contrario.

```
if ($crow['licencia1']=="No"){ 
echo ""; //Si no quieres que se muestre nada solo dejas vacío el echo o no pones nada
}else {
echo "licencia: ".$crow['licencia1']; //si el resultado es "Si" entonces mostrara el contenido que quieras
}
```

Comment: Es la lógica correcta sin embargo ese no es el problema, cuando ejecutó `var_dump($crow);` muestra que los campos no tienen solo la palabra Si o No, tiene 3 caracteres adicionales al inicio de cada palabra

Comment: Ya hice lo mismo de arriba, pero siempre me devuelve el valor de la variable

Comment: Sigue igual, camnbir el tipo de dato en la tabla, le puse text(2) y pasa lo mismo

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra `TEXT` es muy grande mejor usa `CHAR(2)` o `VARCHAR(2)`

Comment: Ya probe asi, pasa lo mismo, no se donde me estoy equivocando, siempre use el if y nunca tube ese tipo de problema

Comment: Ya cambie todos los tipos de datos en la base y sigue igual, no me toma el If